# receiving high frequency data on a c++ tcp client, linux

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I am trying to read high-frequency data from a non-blocking, no-delay, tcp client socket. I do my reading in a spin-loop that basically looks like this:

```
while(true)
{
    r = recv(socket,some_buffer,20000);
    if (r > 0) 
    {         
        cout << calculate_delay() << endl;
    }
}
```

This thread is running on a dedicated core alone, while the whole OS (centos in my case) runs on core 0. So nothing can interfere with my reading loop. I also use a kernel-bypass networboard (solarflare) with openonload driver to bypass the kernel completely when reading my network data. The data comes from a server that is cross-connected with me in a constant 500usec latency line. My problem is that 0.1% of the time the calculate_delay() returns 10,15,100ms delays which is absurd and huge. Why is this happening what could be the cause of it?

The server sends 250bytes packets, sometimes up to 5-10 messages in 1 millisecond.And I also noticed it's possible i receive buffered data reading 500,1000,2000... bytes at once on my receiving socket. 
   Why is this buffering even happening if i read in a spin-loop without delays?

thank you

Comment: My guess is that it’s because of TCP. If your data is packet-oriented, perhaps a packet-oriented protocol would work better.

Comment: Maybe the server wasn't sending anything for a while?

Comment: Do you have source code of "calculate_delay".  Are you sure that iostreams *std::cout" does not affect to your results?

Comment: Did you set TCP_NODELAY flag on sockets?

Comment: @molbdnilo: i can't choose protocol. I know UDP would be better but this is what the server talks. So i have to go with TCP.

Comment: @Sandro. Actually my setup is more complicated but i oversimplified it so that i can explain better my issue. All the loging, measurements, couts i do on another thread. On the reading thread i only buffer data and add to some non-blocking queue, (moodycamel queue). All this i dequeue on another thread, that runs on it's own dedicated core, for calculations,write down,cout.... I also measured my whole code and parts of it but these are all in usecs range. What i see here are delays in milisecond range which is alot more. I even saw 100ms once...

Comment: @Slava, yes thesocket is TCP_NODELAY has O_NONBLOCK (tried also ioctl(sock, FIONBIO, (char *)&on).  I create it like this:  sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); and SO_RCVBUF,SO_SNDBUF,TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP are big enough.

Comment: @rex Server sends data randomly. Sometimes alot, sometimes can be calm. This is a market data server.

Comment: How about sending side?

Comment: @Slava I don't have the sending side but as far as i understand they send 1 message at a time, size about 250bytes. They don't have any cork-ing on or anything buffering before send. It's a market data server that only pushes data as they have without waiting any ack from client side. They don't care if some of my buffers get filled :)

Comment: The issue can be in many places. Some of my guesses are following: You have multithread app, and you pass data from reading thread to another threads by lock-free queue. And you have cache misses during passing these values through queue.

Comment: @NeamtuVictor what do you mean they do not have anything buffering? TCP has it unless you disable with TCP_NODELAY, and what you observe seems to happen on sending site. Setup a wireshark a see what happens, you should start with it.

Comment: @Sandro cache misses would not lead to 100msec delay, no way. This is most probably network issue.

Comment: There can be also issues with your network card and driver setup. Maybe you are using standard liux tcp implementation. Even if your hardware supports kernel bypass mode, maybe you are not using it.

Comment: @Sandro standard linux tcp implementation would not lead to such huge delay.

Comment: Maybe there is just bad connection and there are packet losses

Comment: @Slava: I did tcpdump and analyzed with wireshark. I noticed that indeed wireshark captures big packets from time to time so the data seems allready buffered.  But at the same time i noticed i don't get any tcpdump report if i run using the kernel-bypass driver. So i'm thinking that this buffering it's still possible at my side in the NIC internal buffers? rx-buffer?

Comment: How one related to another? If you use kernel bypass your data would not arrive to OS stack unless you put a flag to do so, so that's normal. So you see data buffered on sender side and that what I try to tell you for so long -
 sender side needs to set TCP_NODELAY,

Comment: @Sandro, msec delays are way bigger than cache misses delays or anything like that indeed. Also there are no errors,dropped, overruns on this network interface.

Comment: @Slava, I think they have TCP_NODELAY on, this server sends mkt data to thousands of people. It's Lmax market data server. But i will ask again some questions on their side to reconfirm all these. When they unthrottle this mkt data flow they usualy ask if you can handle the flow. And they usually don't do it if you are not x-connected with them. It would be funny they have Nagle and TCP_Corking on :).

Comment: They send mkt data to thousands of people and use TCP for that? No way O_o Unthrottle on TCP also does not make much sense, something wrong here.

Comment: @Slava, One more thing to mention. I checked this from different machines and compared with a friend. The delays don't happen at the same time on all of them. So that's why i tend to believe the issue is with me/us. Not with the sending side.

Comment: Each TCP connection is separate so I do not understand what you mean by - delays do not happen at the same time on all of them. Why would you expect it to happen that way? Do they have such delays at all?

Comment: Is [eee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-Efficient_Ethernet) turned off?

Comment: As an aside, you cannot manage what you cannot measure. If there is a delay that you cannot account for then you need to start measuring at other places at lower levels of the networking stack.

Comment: @Slava since the same data is sent to everybody. When more data has to be sent, (crazy market or news conditions) i assumed that all connections should see more or less same delays at about same times. If market is calm and 1 message sent / minute then nobody will have any problem. That was my logic for delays should be at about same times.

Comment: @rex, not sure how to do that on linux? I tried smth like this: ethtool --set-eee enp3s0f1 eee off but the operation not supported. Or is this some setting on the router in between me and server maybe? Please explain. My biggest issue is that i have no access to this router for the x-connect nor the server code. I can only ask questions and observe my delays :).

Comment: I turned off eee on an intel nic by changing the settings of the linux driver provided by intel. Not sure how to do it in general.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion.** If you are asked for additional information, please [edit] it into your question.